# How to differentiate whether Data or QUIC protocol frame follows UDP header?

Tags: wireshark

I am using Wireshark to analyze network traffic and I need to programmatically differentiate whether Data or QUIC protocol frame follows UDP header.

So far, every packet which has source or destination port equal to 80 or 443 I classify as a QUIC protocol packet. But there is a problem: if there is no QUIC protocol header in the packet but only Data (payload) part and if source or destination port is equal to 80 or 443, then again I classify this packet as a QUIC protocol packet but it is not.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

On both of upper images, destination port in UDP header is 443. Therefore, both of packet are classified as QUIC. How can I solve this problem? What checks should I make in order to be sure that it is a QUIC protocol header?

Comment: The question marked as duplicate does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes, it does because it explains that it is a limitation in how Wireshark identifies QUIC. You could work with the Wireshark community to help them narrow it down better, but the interpreter will identify QUIC as it does unless a change is made.

Comment: So, you are telling me that the upper image in my question could also represent QUIC even if that Wireshark does not recognize it as QUIC?

Comment: Then I am not understanding the question. Ar you saying that anything sent to port 80 or 443 Wireshark is defining as QUIC, and you do not want that?

Comment: It is now sounding like you are looking for QUIC specifics, but QUIC is a protocol above OSI layer-4, which makes it explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: No, Wireshark defines most of the packets sent to or received from ports 80 or 443 as QUIC, but the upper image in my question shows that this is not the case all the time. Is this the Wireshark's fault?

Comment: Yes, which is why it is a duplicate of the question as I had marked it before. The answer to that question explained that it was due to the Wireshark dissector for QUIC.

Answer (score 1):

My tests with tshark display filter `gquic.cid` showed the GQUIC packets (from Chrome), but not other test UDP packets I sent to port 443.  Tshark running on same computer as Chrome.

```
 $ tshark -V -Y gquic.cid
 Frame 25: 72 bytes on wire (576 bits), 72 bytes captured (576 bits) on interface 0
 [...]
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0x179e [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 192.168.0.208
    Destination: 216.58.198.227
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 38046, Dst Port: 443
    Source Port: 38046
    Destination Port: 443
    Length: 38
    Checksum: 0xa3b1 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    [Stream index: 3]
GQUIC (Google Quick UDP Internet Connections)
    Public Flags: 0x0c
        .... ...0 = Version: No
        .... ..0. = Reset: No
        .... .1.. = Diversification nonce: Yes
        .... 1... = CID Length: 8 Bytes
        ..00 .... = Packet Number Length: 1 Byte (0x0)
        .0.. .... = Multipath: No
        0... .... = Reserved: 0x0
    CID: 1829611605485631681
    Packet Number: 3
    Payload: 17810e1e6eafe83b6950dedd638591c9807d0252
```

Also, I see Cellstream has published a Wireshark profile for looking at QUIC traffic, their post might be helpful.

- https://www.cellstream.com/reference-reading/tipsandtricks/382-using-wireshark-to-analyze-quic-traffic

Comment: This does not answer my question. Please check update

Comment: Ok now it is clearer. So we can say it is Wireshark's fault?